# create a mysql table view in Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, magento2.3

Anybody know , how we create a MySQL table view in magento 2 programmaticallt

Answer (score 0):

```
  $sql = "CREATE
                SQL SECURITY INVOKER
                VIEW {$viewToLegacyIndex}
                  AS
                    SELECT
                    DISTINCT    
                      legacy_stock_status.product_id,
                      legacy_stock_status.website_id,
                      legacy_stock_status.stock_id,
                      legacy_stock_status.qty quantity,
                      legacy_stock_status.stock_status is_salable,
                      product.sku
                    FROM {$legacyStockStatusTable} legacy_stock_status
                      INNER JOIN {$productTable} product
                        ON legacy_stock_status.product_id = product.entity_id;";
        $this->schemaSetup->getConnection()->query($sql);
```

You can get reference from below magento default file.

vendor/magento/module-inventory-catalog/Setup/Patch/Schema/CreateLegacyStockStatusView.php file

Comment: Thanks, i will check and let you know